# programmatically uninstall other application without asking user

Tags: android, web-applications, uninstallation, android-applicationinfo

I have system-level app with

Device is not rooted! `INSTALL_PACKAGES` and `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` permission is included to Manifest

Can I install and Uninstall any apk silently ?

Comment: `ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE` is not a permission.

Comment: i was developed following code but it will prompt user to asking uninstall app but i want to without ask it

Comment: Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:com.example.onlinemcqexam"); Intent uninstallIntent =        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
              startActivity(uninstallIntent);

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can uninstall app without user confirmation

But uninstall app use the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.example.getgoogleaccount"));
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: your code is working fine but it will prompt to ask user to uninstall application i want that will not prompt anymore

Comment: "I don't think you can uninstall app without user confirmation". I mention this in my answer. In fact i also try to do the same not uninstall . I try to install application. But android system not allowing me to do that without user confirmation.